# Windows and Detecting Captive Portals

Tags: c#, windows, network-programming

Trying to detect when a Captive Portal is in use on a internet connection i.e a laptop connected at a coffee shop.

Trying to achieve this using the Network List Manager COM Object:

```
NETWORKLIST.NetworkListManager _networkListManager = new NetworkListManager();
foreach (INetworkConnection net in _networkListManager.GetNetworkConnections())
{                
    if (net.GetConnectivity().HasFlag(NLM_CONNECTIVITY.NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_INTERNET) == true)
      {
           // Check if we are connected by a captive web portal
           // using NLM_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY_WEBHIJACK
      }                                
 }
```

According to the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370750(v=vs.85).aspx

"These connectivity flags can be retrieved by querying for the NA_InternetConnectivityV4 or NA_InternetConnectivityV6 properties using the IPropertyBag interface for an INetwork or INetworkConnection interface"

I appears that the NA_InternetConnectivityV4 enumerations are not present (incomplete implementation) or I don't know how to work with them.

Has anyone actually used this or have ideas on ways to detect when a captive portal is in use?

Comment: Do you have a solution for C#? I'm trying to detect captive portals in a UWP App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not C# but I found those APIs to be working on C++

pNetworkListManager->GetNetworks (NLM_ENUM_NETWORK_CONNECTED, &pEnum)
    INetwork *pINetwork;

```
//Should actually loop through the possible networks.
HRESULT hr = pEnum->Next(1, &pINetwork, nullptr);

IPropertyBag *pNetworkPropertyBag;
HRESULT hrQueryInterface = pINetwork->QueryInterface(IID_IPropertyBag, (LPVOID*)&pNetworkPropertyBag);
if (SUCCEEDED(hrQueryInterface 1) && pNetworkPropertyBag != nullptr)
{
    NLM_CONNECTIVITY networkConnectivity;
    VARIANT variantConnectivity;

    if (SUCCEEDED(pINetwork->GetConnectivity(&networkConnectivity)))
    {
        if ((networkConnectivity & 
        NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_INTERNET) == NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_INTERNET)
        {
            VariantInit(&variantConnectivity);
            if (SUCCEEDED(pNetworkPropertyBag->Read(NA_InternetConnectivityV4, &variantConnectivity, nullptr)) && (V_UINT(&variantConnectivity) & NLM_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY_WEBHIJACK) == NLM_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY_WEBHIJACK)
            {
                //Captive Portal detected
            }
            VariantClear(&variantConnectivity);
    }
}
```

Check this for full details: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088221/Captive-Portal-Detection-with-Windows-APIs

Answer (score 0):

Closing this one, investigations showed that NA_InternetConnectivityV4 enumerations are not present and the MSDN documentation is incorrect.